# Connect AWS ElasticBeanstalk to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is the simplest way to let AWS connect to Atlas without allowing connections from any IP?
[Looks like](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-static-IP-address/) when you create a new environment in EBS you can choose to have an Elastic IP. Assuming this would work, it looks like you can only set this when you create an environment. Doesn't seem I can edit the Network settings of my running environments (and doesn't even look like I can pause the environment, assuming that's the reason why the Network bit is not modifiable).

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is pretty late, but I think the best way would be to set up VPC peering. I think you will have to use a custom VPC within AWS to be able to do that.
See Atlas network access

[image: VPC Peering]